$T + \|T\| \cdot \bf 1$ is a positive operator?
I'm look at a proof where the author claims that we may assume that a self-adjoint operator $T$ is in fact positive by replacing $T$ with $T + \|T\| \cdot 1$...why can we do this?
Is $T + \|T\| \cdot \bf 1$ always a positive operator? Why?
Seems like a simple result, but I'm not seeing it.
Theorem III.4 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0402056
Note: edited for clarity.

By "positive operator" you mean self-adjoint and positive semidefinite, right?  What have you tried so far?

Suppose BWOC that $T$ is not positive, then there exists some $x$ with $\langle Tx, x\rangle < 0$...I think the result is proved if we can show that $\langle Tx, x\rangle \leq |T| \cdot \langle x, x \rangle$...this seems plausible, since
$$|T| = \sup_{|x| = 1} \langle Tx, x\rangle$$
...sups are big...It seems like it should be trivial, but I am stuck.

Hang on...supposing that $\langle Tx, x\rangle < 0$ show that $\langle Tx, x\rangle \leq |T| \cdot |x|^2$? That simple? Oof. Trivial indeed, my apologies.

You need an absolute value in there somewhere...

You are almost there. You have, for $x$ with $\|x\|=1$,
$$
\langle (T+\|T\|)x,x\rangle=\langle Tx,x\rangle+\|T\|\geq\langle Tx,x\rangle+|\langle Tx,x\rangle|\geq0. 
$$
So $T+\|T\|$ is positive.
You could also deduce this from the fact that the spectral radius is at most the norm. As a selfadjoint operator has real spectrum, $\sigma(T)\subset [-\|T\|,\|T\|]$. Then $\sigma(T+\|T\|)\subset[0,2\|T\|]$ and hence $T+\|T\|$ is positive (since it is also selfadjoint).

Thank you! Oof, the look on my prof's face if I try to bring spectral radius into this...
